# What are the alternatives we have to the VEDA 4 vibrational energy distribution analysis software?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software, ir-spectroscopy

Said software is very useful when you need to assign the peaks in vibrational spectra to different vibrational modes found in a hessian calculation for a given molecule, as described in [Jamróz, Michał H. “Vibrational Energy Distribution Analysis (VEDA): Scopes and Limitations”. Spectrochimica Acta Part A: Molecular and Biomolecular Spectroscopy, vol. 114, outubro de 2013, p. 220–30. ScienceDirect, doi:10.1016/j.saa.2013.05.096.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1386142513005891) It's becoming popular, the paper has nearly 450 citations as of april 2020, but it has some downsides for me:

- Despite being a freeware that can be downloaded from [their site](https://smmg.pl/software/veda) by anyone, it's not [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Free_Software_Definition), or at least open source, and it's windows-only;
- Doesn't support people using free tools like [Gamess-US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAMESS_(US)) or [Psi4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSI_(computational_chemistry)), only accepting Gaussian output files as its input, a paid and very expensive quantum chemistry software;

So I did some research for alternatives that could avoid these downsides. Among the citations to the VEDA paper, I've found what seems to be a alternative approach to solve the same problem, as described in [Teixeira, Filipe, e M. Natália D. S. Cordeiro. “Improving Vibrational Mode Interpretation Using Bayesian Regression”. Journal of Chemical Theory and Computation, vol. 15, no 1, janeiro de 2019, p. 456–70. ACS Publications, doi:10.1021/acs.jctc.8b00439.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jctc.8b00439) Their software, called vibAnalysis, is open source, and available from a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/teixeirafilipe/vibAnalysis). It doesn't support Gamess-US or Psi4, but at least supports [ORCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORCA_(quantum_chemistry_program)), which is free for academics, besides Gaussian.

I wonder if there are other alternatives I have missed in my research, specially if they run on linux and work with Gamess-US or Psi4. If somebody here could provide some guidance, I'd be grateful.

Comment: This question would fit well on the new Materials Modeling SE: https://materials.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If somebody stumbles in this question, I got some helpful comments in https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/411/243